# How should I proceed for building a website where you can play chess with other people?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, chess

I'm a beginner: I know HTML/CSS and a little Javascript. Also, I've started learning Python.

As a first personal objective, I want to build a site where you can play with friends simply by sending them a URL (like lichess.org does). No need for registration.
Could I create the chessboard and the pieces just with javascript? If not, is Python a good language for such a task? Where can I find a guide for building simple games?

Comment: sure ... start by writing some code that enforces move rules ... (afaik there is actually some libraries out there that do this... but then you have to learn the library) (or even simpler ... just code that draws the board and pieces

Comment: There's a new start-up company called Google that can actually search the interwebs for you and give you an answer to this...it isn't a very big or well known company but, give them a shot?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a starting point.

if you are looking to built something from the ground up. I'd start with programming the logic of each of the chess pieces. Then implement that onto a board, then implement that with all other game rules.

Any language can achieve what you are trying to do. Python is as good as any to do that.

I'm guessing you didn't spend a lot of time googling this, here's some info:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/160740/best-approach-for-writing-a-chess-engine

Forget the multiplayer stuff for now. Start with building the game.

Comment: I actually spent a lot of time instead, but i only found too specific or unrelated stuff: for instance, I don't want to build a chess engine, and most of the content I found it was related to that, like your link.
Although in your link I found some interesting stuff anyways, thanks